# array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

i need to do array and then send in php file with help ajax.
I have code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.photo-user-change').bind('click', function(){
        var hasclass = $(this).hasClass('active');
        if(hasclass == true) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var iwa = $('.active').attr('id');
            alert(iwa);
        }
    });
});
```

and html:

```
<ul>
  <li class="photo-user-change" id="1">1</li>
  <li class="photo-user-change" id="2">2</li>
  <li class="photo-user-change" id="3">3</li>
</ul>
```

When added class 'active' need introduce ID into an array and then sent this array in php file. ID maybe a few.

How do this? I need create multi selector. thanks.

Comment: You need to better define your problem. First, what purpose overall is the code serving? You have an event handler for the `click` event on all elements of class `photo-user-change`, but what are those elements? Links, photos, divs?  When [users] click, what do they expect to do?  What does the array need to store, multiple IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way to get all elements with the class `active` and `photo-user-change` and create a comma separated list of their `id` attribute. This could easily be converted to JSON format - for your PHP web-service. You would place this right before you fire off the web service call.

```
var ids = $('.photo-user-change.active').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join(',');

alert(ids);
```

See it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/XSRUb/